# How to get drop frames in UWP MediaElement?

Tags: c#, uwp, mediaelement

How can I get the number of frames being dropped during playback. I'm using UWP MediaElement.

In Silverlight, I can easily get drop frames as shown in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.droppedframespersecond(v=vs.95).aspx

But in UWP, that functionality seems missing. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.aspx

Comment: You can give the Grid to drop.

Comment: @lindexi I have no clue what are you talking about.

Comment: The Grid that is the parent of MediaElement can be gave to drop.

Comment: @lindexi Please read the question properly before trying to answer.

Comment: I dont know what your question so I add comment rather answer.

Comment: @indexi Please read the question properly before trying to *comment*.

Comment: For my suggestion, in order to get the number of drop frame, decoding the movie as the images and calculate.And sorry for my hasty.